# Cassandra, removing old, not needed data

Tags: cassandra

I have a two-node Cassandra cluster, with RF of 2. So both nodes contain 100% of data.

Now, I am running short on disk space. I can remove some old data, since they were aggregated and processed before, and I don't need them anymore.

I tried running a `delete` query from `cqlsh`, but I get a timeout. I tried increasing timeouts, but it seems that running a query from `cqlsh` will take much more time.

How can I disable this timeout for a single query or connection? Is there any other way, besides increasing timeout, to remove some data from a node?

My Cassandra version is `3.11.0`.

PS. I increases `write_request_timeout_in_ms` in `cassandra.yaml`. Is this the correct one for `delete` queries?

Answer (score 0):

Deletes really shouldn't timeout unless there is a problem related to something else. Its inserting a tombstone with no reads or anything and should be fast/cheap regardless of what exists already. Reading on other hand can be impacted a lot. I would guess GC related problems related to reads. You could check GC logs and maybe increase heap and reduce `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction` (if using cms and not g1).

So check GC and normal logs for issues (look for WARN, ERROR in system log) and at pause times in gc logs >1 second, there should be none.

After issuing delete you could try to do a force compaction (`nodetool compact keyspace table`) to see if it helps disk space. The delete by itself will not reduce disk space until the data has been compacted with the tombstone.

`write_request_timeout_in_ms` is the right setting, but if your hitting it something is wrong and your just masking it. It should really take less than 1 millisecond normal use.

Side note: RF=2 on a 2 node cluster is not how C* is designed to run. You have no availability on a database that sacrificed consistency for high availability.